# How to handle localNotifications when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift4, uilocalnotification, userinfo, remote-notifications

I've searched in all questions here but no solution worked.

I scheduled localNotifications with a userInfo option.
When app is in foreground, the notification arrived and a can handle perfectly with this function that system calls by itself.

- For local notifications

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

      if application.applicationState == .active {
          return
      }

      //My implementation
  }
  ```
- For remote notifications

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

      if application.applicationState == .active {
          return
      }

      //My implementation
  }
  ```

But the problem is, when app is closed, this functions are not called and I can't handle the data that I need.

I've tried get userInfo in that function in appDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let localUserInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {

        // My implementation
    } else if let remoteUserInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {

        // My implementation
    }
    return true
}
```

But.. Didn't work...

Someone could help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you registered for notifications?
In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions():

```
    // Register Notifications
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { granted, error in

                if granted {
                    print("User notifications are allowed")
                } else {
                    print("User notifications are NOT allowed")
                }
            })
            application.registerForRemoteNotification()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Then you should catch local notifications in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        completionHandler()
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not using UNNotificationCenter. To get permission I'm using application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil))

Comment: registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings  is deprecated since iOS10. User UNUserNotificationCenter instead. Try my code

Comment: The problem is that I configure my notifications using UILocalNotifications (I need to have support to ios 9.0 and later). And UNUserNotificationCenter is just for ios 10.0 and later....

Comment: I used UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self and worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will get the notification in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if the user clicks it whether it's local or remote , otherwise you won't know except if store them in server and pull them every time you open the app

Comment: But, like I told in question, launchOptions are nil even when I click in notification when app are closed.

Comment: can you print the content without casting like print(launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification])